# Docker-compose containers refuse connection

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I',m trying to create e simple python-flask api connected to a postgress database,

So added to my docker-compose.yaml my api, db and pgadmin but when I try to start my docker-composer container it doens't

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build: ./Backend/src
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      STAGE: test
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: postgresql+psycopg2://test:test@db/test
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app/app
    restart: always

  db:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    image: postgres:latest
    networks:
      - local
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admim
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    networks:
      - local
    restart: always

  networks:
    local:
      driver: bridge
```

Running the docker from pycharm I get this error:

```
Deploying 'Compose: docker-compose-dev.yaml'...
Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker-compose-dev.yaml': Sorry but parent: com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewImpl[,0,0,1008x155,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=] has already been disposed (see the cause for stacktrace) so the child: com.intellij.util.Alarm@56e3f4b will never be disposed
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; it doesn't usually make sense to connect to it.  Where exactly are you providing that database address?  Is the process that's using it in a container or not?  What's the exact error you get?

Comment: I tryied also with 127.0.0.1, but I think my containes has another ip, anyway, don't know why it does not start

Comment: Please edit the question to include the exact error you get; just "it doesn't start" isn't really enough to diagnose it further.  Glancing at the file, the `api` and `db` containers aren't on the same `networks:` and this could cause connectivity problems; the easiest workaround is to delete every `networks:` block in the whole file to let every container use the Compose-provided `default` network.

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry but i'm not familiar with docker, removing the network tags the container starts and I'm able to connect to my db